# Your script, Email Studio, has recently failed to finish successfully

Tags: email

I'm getting a daily email from apps-scripts-notifications@google.com stating that

> Your script, Email Studio, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

I have no idea what this is, but it lists 24 errors (see below) every day. Any advice as to what the problem is, what I should do about it and how to stop the daily email alerts would be much appreciated.

> Summary:
>
> ```
> Error Message Count
>
> Authorization is required to perform that action. 24
> Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
> 9/21/18 3:13 AM triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  9/21/18 3:13 AM
> 9/21/18 4:13 AM triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  9/21/18 4:13 AM
> ```
>
> Etc etc...
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Google Apps Script

Comment: No one got any idea on this? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with specifically Email Studio. Going to https://www.google.com/script/start/, choosing Edit, and "All your triggers", allows you to delete the Email Studio trigger.